# Fat burning exercises meaningful only three times a week?

Tags: weight-loss

I use an elliptical cross trainer for fat burning exercises. Normally, they recommend to exercise three times a week. given I could exercise daily, what is a meaningful optimal training plan? (my current BMI is 32, and it used to be 26.5 a couple of years ago).

Why is this question not for opinion based answers?

- Can i.e. is known - facts -  daily elliptical training cause negative health effects e.g. on the knees?

Comment: There’s no such thing as a fat burning exercise. While physical activity can certainly impact your net energy balance, fat loss is independent from physical activity. This is a case of correlation not equating causation.

Comment: What is your actual goal? If you only want to lose weight, you do not need to overthink this. Do some exercising if you have the time. If you however want to reach some other goal, you might want to look at how to get there in a good way. I do not know what a good goal besides doing some exercising to help with weight loss might be for a elliptical cross trainer, but maybe you do

Comment: @J.Doe Welcome to Physical Fitness!  This question is likely to get subjective answers, which aren't a good fit for the Q/A style of this site.  Try to edit it to ask for a very specific, objective piece of information.  As it stands, the question is likely to be closed as Opinion Based.

Comment: Your primary issue, as best I can tell, is that you ask for the "meaningful optimal training plan" but we really don't know enough about your state of fitness or your goals to provide a correct answer. Thus, we'd just be giving our opinions.

Comment: Alternately, asking whether a "fat burning exercise" is meaningful only if done three times a week is perfectly fine, and is answerable.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your goal is to lose fat. For this you need to be in a long-term caloric deficit. This is studied [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18025815). Keep in mind that these ladies only did aerobic training which does not significantly increase muscle mass, thus they found that between dieting heavily and exercising and dieting both led to the same amount of fat loss when the caloric deficit was same.

It is definitely not true that calorically demanding exercises are only useful three times a week. If you can do it more often then do so. Keep in mind that the most important thing for health and weightloss is dieting and metabolism. [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3696577/) covers the importance of a low-calorie for cardiovascular health, more so than just fat loss. These results should be taken with a grain of salt due to small sample of human trials, but it is some evidence nonetheless.

If you really wanna lose weight, you're better off doing strength training and weight lifting. The added muscle will boost your metabolism causing you to burn more calories just being alive. To be totally honest, I couldn't find a paper giving evidence. I did however find [this WebMD article](https://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/features/get-more-burn-from-your-workout#) that isn't necessarily trustworthy. I want to say I believe it but that may just be confirmation bias so I'll leave it up to you to decide.

[This paper](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/103/3/738/4564609) is just interesting.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include references.

Answer (score -2):

The best thing you can do is to educate yourself on the topic. Physical fitness is very very broad subject and it is impossible to answer your question because it's too simplistic. I encourage you to check out Joe Rogan episodes with people like Peter attia, chris chressser, Rhonda Patrick. Learn about endocrinology of this stuff. Learn about what to eat. Applying this knowledge will burn much more fat than any strategy on elliptical.